# s3 presigned url with checksum algortihm ignored

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a put `presigned_url` with this code:

```java
public URL generatePushResourceLocation(DocumentId documentId, String contentMD5) {
    String key = documentId.getId().toString();
    PutObjectRequest.Builder putObjectRequestBuilder = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key);

    putObjectRequestBuilder.checksumAlgorithm(ChecksumAlgorithm.SHA256);

    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = putObjectRequestBuilder.build();
    PutObjectPresignRequest request = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder().putObjectRequest(putObjectRequest)
            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).build();

    PresignedPutObjectRequest presignPutObject = s3Presigner.presignPutObject(request);
    URL signedPutURL = presignPutObject.url();

    log.info("Push presigned URL with MD5 content: {}", signedPutURL.toString());

    return signedPutURL;
}
```

The generated url sample is like:

> http://localstack.localhost:8000/espaidoc/9a6f8254-502b-4a44-b82a-5fb16022e8fd?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240308T120347Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-sdk-checksum-algorithm&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Credential=test%2F20240308%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1df5154810a2b11136c9425333c139ac0a1c4d6537de2d372e74645be7ab22c3

As you can see, a `x-amz-sdk-checksum-algorithm` parameter is appended.

When I make the PUT using generated presigned_url everything seems to work, but when I'm trying to get object attributes, I'm not getting any `ChecksumSHA256`:

```bash
$ aws s3api get-object-attributes --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --object-attributes "ObjectSize" "Checksum" | yq .
{
  "LastModified": "2024-03-08T12:05:24+00:00",
  "ObjectSize": 2333
}
```

I'm trying to simulate this behavior using `cli`:

```bash
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --body pom.xml --checksum-algorithm SHA256 | yq .
{
  "ETag": "\"44a7a97ddff52b27557a39cb2983ae62\"",
  "ChecksumSHA256": "ZR6CNpjrGvQWPPkaHiAeTWm2La1ZZIHLjtrFaPjnaPc=",
  "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"
}
```

Also, I'm able to get object attributes like:

```bash
$ aws s3api get-object-attributes --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --object-attributes "ObjectSize" "Checksum" | yq .
{
  "LastModified": "2024-03-08T12:01:16+00:00",
  "Checksum": {
    "ChecksumSHA256": "ZR6CNpjrGvQWPPkaHiAeTWm2La1ZZIHLjtrFaPjnaPc="
  },
  "ObjectSize": 2097
}
```

Isn't it able to set a checksum algorithm on presigned PUT url?